# What is the significance of Library Version in shared Object file

Tags: c, shared-libraries

When we created shared object file why we do versioning of it, for example

```
/libnetsnmp.so.5.0.9 
libzebra.so -> libzebra.so.0.0.0
libzebra.so.0 -> libzebra.so.0.0.0
```

Isn't creating just ".so" file is not enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be needed to make multiple versions of the library coexist, having one particular version as the default; or to see at glance which precise version of library is installed, and the symlink lets the applications refer to the non-versioned filename (which is important, otherwise you would have to recompile the applications at every minor library update).